# Does AWS console consumes any additional API besides the ones publicly available

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

AWS console provides a user interface and consumes AWS APIs underneath to manage resources. My question is does it use any additional API besides the ones that are publicly available through their restful API? In other words, have you seen things you can do through the console that you can't do through API (or a combination of APIs)?

Comment: There are a few features that are console-only.  Where are you going with this question?

Comment: What features specifically? I'd like to know what extra features it has and why those features are not in API in terms of security and other aspects.

Comment: CloudFront usage reports and graphs, CloudWatch graphs and dashboards, and the billing tools come to mind.  All of them are based on data that is accessible via APIs, but there is no programmatic way to access these aggregated/summarized reporting and presentation elements (e.g. you can't embed a CloudWatch graph into a web page), but the common thread is that they are all *analysis*-type features.  There's nothing *operational* that isn't API accessible that I can think of.

Comment: A bit of history: In the beginning, there was _only_ the API. The management console was added later to provide a user-friendly interface. Many companies choose to only use the API or [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), without using the management console.